# How to update an XML document with Ant

Tags: xml, ant, xpath, xml-namespaces

My goal is to simply update the "lastmod" node in a simple sitemap xml document:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<urlset xmlns="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9">
    <url>
        <loc>http://www.example.com/</loc>
        <lastmod>2005-01-01</lastmod>
    </url>
</urlset>
```

I want to do this as part of my deploy ant script so I am using the Ant task [XMLTask](http://www.oopsconsultancy.com/software/xmltask/). Here is my ant target:

```
<target name="update-sitemap" description="update the update date">
    <xmltask source="war/sitemap.xml" dest="war/newsitemap.xml" report="true">
        <replace path="/urlset/url/lastmod/text()" withText="new text"/>
    </xmltask>
</target>
```

Unfortunately, my xpath fails to match anything:

```
[xmltask] TextAction(new text) (/urlset/url/lastmod/text()) failed to match
```

I have also tried the following xpath queries with no luck:

```
//lastmod/text()
/urlset[@*]/url/lastmod/text()
/urlset[@xmlns]/url/lastmod/text()
```

I have however discovered that if I manually remove the namespace attribute from the urlset node in my source file, everything works ok.
Is this a bug in XMLTask or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Typically you need to register namespaces. The method depends on your XPath engines. In this case (an XML syntax) I would expect that declaring a namespace in your Ant document was enough.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to tell XPath that all nodes have a namespace by prefixing with a colon. The correct expression is:

```
/:urlset/:url/:lastmod/text()
```

Answer (score 2):

I couldn't solve the problem. I'm certain XMLTask has some problem when the attribute is "xmlns" because everything works as expected if I rename it to something else ("xmln" for example).

I've simply resigned to using a slightly uglier regex replacement technique:

```
<replaceregexp byline="true">
    <regexp pattern="      &lt;lastmod&gt;(.*)&lt;/lastmod&gt;"/>
    <substitution expression="      &lt;lastmod&gt;new text&lt;/lastmod&gt;"/>
    <fileset file="war/sitemap.xml" />
</replaceregexp>
```

On the plus side, this doesn't require any third party libs.

**Update**: Solved it now. See my other answer.

Comment: This `xmlns="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9"` is not an attribute but a namespace declaration.

Comment: Initially I didn't think XPath would know the difference. I understand why now I think about it.

Answer (score 0):

I needed to do a replace within the same ant file which is tricky as the regex replace operation would also update my regex pattern itself. The solution was to not match the regex pattern signature for example like so will work:

```
<replaceregexp file="${ant.file}"
    match='(name="staticresource.foldername_previous" value=")[^\[\]]*(")'  
    replace='\1${staticresource.foldername}\2'
    byline="true"
/>
```