# Log4j Properties File Configuration

Tags: log4j

I'm using `Log4j` for logging my system events.

Initially I used the `Log4j` properties file and then shifted to `log4j.xml` file.

My application has another property file - `system.properties` - that takes the configuration parameters.

I want the log output file to be specified in the application properties file - `system.properties` and refer the properties file in the `log4j.xml` file and also update the configuration.

Is it possible with this `log4j.xml` configuration?

Comment: No, why cant you update log output file in log4j.xml itself ?

Comment: Instead Of updating in two places I want to do it in one place.

Comment: Log4j xml configuration doesn't provide any means to read/load property file. It would be better to mention the log file name in log4j.xml only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it by using ant scripts. Load the system.properties file in ant and replace the value inside the log4j.xml file.

Refer to this link on how to update XML file.
[How to update an XML document with Ant](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5739210/how-to-update-an-xml-document-with-ant)